# Проверка авторизации vk.api

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется такой код:

```
import vk
def authorize(self):
    text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
    session = vk.Session(access_token='{}'.format(text))
    api = vk.API(session)
```

Я хочу проверить, авторизован ли пользователь после выполнения этой функции или нет. Каким образом это можно сделать? Возможно, есть какой-то метод, возвращающий 1, если пользователь авторизован и 0, если нет? Искал все, что связано с проверкой авторизации, но годного ничего не нашел.

Comment: Укажите, какую библиотеку используете.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Указал

Comment: советую сделать вопрос более развернутым и уточнить что именно у Вас не получается.